# Param is missing or the value is empty for: contact

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following form validations for name and email:

```
 validates :name,  presence: true
 validates :email, presence: true
```

In my browser it looks like:

[image]

But, when I submit the following form:

```
 = simple_form_for @contact, :url => create_enquiry_path, :method => :post do |form|
    = form.input :name
    = form.input :email
    = form.input :phone
    = form.input :website
```

There are no errors on the page, but I get:

```
 param is missing or the value is empty for: contact
```

My controller is:

```
def create
 @contact = ContactForm.new(form_params)

 if @contact.errors.any?
   render :action => :new
   flash[:error] = 'Please correct errors.'
 else
    redirect_to ....
    flash[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message. We will contact you soon!'
 end

private

def form_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :phone, :email, :website)
end
```

Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `require(:contact)`, but nowhere in your form do you actually have a `:contact` field.

Comment: Can you also include _console error_ logs ?

Comment: @MarcB and you suggest changing '@contact' to ':contact'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your parameters dictionary is structured differently than you're expecting. If your params dictionary is coming to your controller like:

```
{ :name => 'John', :email => 'john.smith@abc.ca', ...... }
```

Then change your `form_params` method to:

```
def form_params
  params.permit(:name, :phone, :email, :website)
end
```

If your params dictionary is coming to your controller like:

```
{ :contact_form => { :name => 'John', :email => 'john.smith@abc.ca', ...... } }
```

Then change your `form_params` method to (based on @JiříPospíšil's suggestion):

```
def form_params
  params.require(:contact_form).permit(:name, :phone, :email, :website)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If the name of the model is `ContactForm`, then `form_params` should reference `:contact_form`, not `:contact`.